# Has my Ubuntu laptop been hacked through Facebook with Firefox?

Tags: firefox, facebook, hacking

Since two days everytime I log into facebook with Firefox with my 16.04 Ubuntu laptop I have several adwares webpages (such as macOS, for instance) that adds themselves in new tabs. I didn't thought it was possible to hack an Ubuntu laptop...

- What may allow this hack to be possible ?
- What may I do to fix this ?

Here is several screenshot of those pages :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is a screenshot of my addons after removing flash :

[image]

Comment: First you should check whether any add-ons etc got installed to Firefox. Visit the add-ons page from the menu or at `about:addons` and check for any suspicious entries and remove them. You could also simply nuke your whole Firefox profile by deleting the `.mozilla` folder in your home directory (you must enable showing hidden files to see it: CTRL+H), it will create a new default one when you start it the next time. Beware that this destroys all your saved Firefox bookmarks, passwords, settings, add-ons etc.

Comment: @ByteCommander Thanks, this is useful. I think I downloaed adobe flash from a malicious website...

Comment: But wait, Flash is a different thing. Flash is a plug-in, which is installed and stored outside of the browser. And depending on how you installed it, you might have infected the entire system with something. Please describe what exactly you did and where you got it from.

Comment: @ByteCommander I don't exactly remember... I was on awebsite I found suspect but it asked me to download flash to see a video if I remember well. I did, it seemed to work and since then It seemed that I have issues. Anyway I added a picture of my addons...

Comment: "I was on a website I found suspect but it asked me to download flash to see a video" yeah... that was it. Uninstall it, and try running ClamAV to check for further damage.

Comment: @Marine1, try refreshing firefox, `Tools > Restart with addons disabled > Refresh`

Comment: @heynnema What is ClamAV ? I looked on their website but I want to be sure not downloading something bad twice !

Comment: ClamAV is an anti-virus app that runs on Ubuntu. Install `clamtk` and `clamav` using Synaptic or the Ubuntu Software Center, and then run clamtk from the Unity dashboard and scan your system.

Comment: @heynnema So what should I put in the button to *check or recheck a file's reputation* ? Which has a (none) option for the moment ? File system ?

Comment: Are you looking at the clamtk interface? You want to scan your entire file system, starting at /.

Comment: @heynnema Yes, I was, I did Scan a directory and it scanned the 33 files of `/home/user` finding no threats. I don't know how to scan the whole `/`

Comment: Choose `Scan a directory` and specify `/`. Also, check the settings for recursive directory scans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

*"I was on a website I found suspect but it asked me to download flash to see a video"* yeah... that was it. Uninstall it, and try running ClamAV to check for further damage.

ClamAV is an anti-virus app that runs on Ubuntu. Install `clamtk` and `clamav` using Synaptic or the Ubuntu Software Center, and then run clamtk from the Unity dashboard and scan your system.

**Check the settings for recursive directory scans.** To scan your entire file system, choose `Scan a directory` and specify `/`.

Comment: Alas, it tells me I scanned 0 file when I specifiy /... Maybe I should show you some screenshots to show you...

Comment: @Marine1 did you checkmark recursive directory scans?

Comment: Ow! Indeed! It works now ! And what about clamav ? I downloaded it and exported it on my desktop but don't know what to do from there

Comment: @Marine1 what do you mean that you downloaded it and exported it to your desktop? Didn't you use Synaptic or Software Center to install it?

Comment: Nein, not for clamav, only clamtk was found on ubuntu Software

Comment: @Marine1 if you did a scan, then clamtk included clamav.

Answer (score 0):

This could be simply some annoying pop up adds.  I use Adblock Plus on my systems. While I don't normally use Firefox, I have seen some terribly annoying pop up ads lately. If you don't nuke Firefox, I'd clear out all the cookies, and see what your home page is setup to be. Revert it back to what you think it ought to be. Flash is a common entry point for malware, and I'd advise to only install it from known sources.